# Spring Security: @PreAuthorized(hasAuthority ) with list as parameters

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

Is it possible to use @PreAuthorize and hasAuthority with a list of values?

```
@PostMapping("/post")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(#parameters.list)")
public Dto myController() {
   //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use hasAnyAuthority?

which would be your use case?

Comment: Thank you! That's was my solution.
I didn't check the documentation and came here looking for help.